# Que hace el metodo "paint(Graphics g)" de la clase Component? (JAVA)

Tags: java, paint

Quisiera sabes que hace exactamente y porque las subclases lo reescriben? Lo único que he notando es que al colocarlo se redibuja todo el componente, es decir se borra todo y vueve a dibujar, ¿por que pasa eso?, y para finalizar por que el metodo "paint(Graphics g)" de cuaquier objeto que herede aguna subclase de "Component" como por ejemplo una clase que herede de "Canvas", se ejecuta automáticamente?

Puede parecer algo tonto, pero es una duda que no me deja tranquilo desde que la tengo, Gracias anticipadas.

Aqui un pequeño fragmento de codigo para ilustrar un poco:

```
public class Lienzo extends Canvas{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawRect(10,10,50,50);
        super.paint(g);
    }
}
```

Ese método de la clase Lienzo, se ejecuta automáticamente sin yo invocarlo.

Answer (score 2):

Java proporciona la clase Graphics, que permite dibujar elipses, cuadrados, líneas, mostrar texto y también tiene muchos otros métodos de dibujo.
La clase Graphics proporciona el entorno de trabajo para cualquier operación gráfica que se realice dentro del AWT.

Para poder pintar, un programa necesita un contexto gráfico válido, representado por una instancia de la clase Graphics. Pero esta clase no se puede instanciar directamente; así que debemos crear un componente y pasarlo al programa como un argumento al método paint().

El único argumento del método paint() es un objeto de esta clase. La clase Graphics dispone de métodos para soportar tres categorías de operaciones gráficas:

1. Dibujo de primitivas gráficas,
2. Dibujo de texto,
3. Presentación de imágenes en formatos *.gif y *.jpeg.

Tiene diferentes metodos, puedes conocerlos aqui:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

Answer (score 1):

El método paint(Graphics g) dibuja un componente visual de awt, y es llamado cada vez que un elemento debe ser dibujado.

Te recomiendo leer la documentación al respecto para aclarar más dudas.

[Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html#:%7E:text=The%20Paint%20Method,-Regardless%20of%20how&text=When%20AWT%20invokes%20this%20method,to%20the%20component%27s%20font%20property.)